# IOS- pjsua_call_make_call function is not working in PJSIP Lib

Tags: ios, swift, call, sip, pjsip

Using this link https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started we are integrate PJSIP lib in our application.

```
        pjsua_call_setting_default(&opt);
        opt.aud_cnt = 1;
        opt.vid_cnt = 1;
        
         print("Destinlation URL:\(pjsip_vars.dest)")
        let dest_str = strdup(pjsip_vars.dest);
        var dest:pj_str_t = pj_str(dest_str);
        status = pjsua_call_make_call(account_id, &dest, &opt, nil, nil, &pjsip_vars.call_id);//&pjsip_vars.call_id
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue)
        {
            print("error making in call")
           //pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error making call", status);
        }
```

User added successfully but when a make call just audio play user is not available in server but **incoming call** working perfectly in same server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you